# C Issue Regarding Declarations

Tags: c, function-pointers, swap

I found the following C program these lines and don't know what they mean and do:

```
    int (*less)(void *m, size_t a, size_t b);
    int (*less)(void *m, size_t a, size_t b);
    void (*swap)(void *m, size_t a, size_t b);
```

and what are they equivalent to?

Answer (score 1):

The declarations are for function pointers, designed to point to functions with different signatures.

```
int (*less)(void *m, size_t a, size_t b);
```

This one is a function pointer called 'less', which is to be used with a function which takes a parameter list of (void *m, size_t a, size_t b), and return int. You could point this function pointer at a function like this:

```
int foo(void *m, size_t a, size_t b)
{
    return 0;
}
```

The second one is the same. The third one is this:

```
void (*swap)(void *m, size_t a, size_t b);
```

This one is a function pointer called 'swap', which is to be used with a function which takes a parameter list of (void *m, size_t a, size_t b), and return void. You could point this function pointer at a function like this:

```
void foo(void *m, size_t a, size_t b)
{
    return;
}
```

This [website](http://cdecl.org/) is handy for decoding these kinds of declarations.

Answer (score 0):

They describe pointers to functions.
See another SO question about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work)